# [ROS2] Service header files

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

source: https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclcpp/minimal_client/main.cpp

In the example of the service Client they use following header file:

```
#include "example_interfaces/srv/add_two_ints.hpp"
```

I think it is necessary to make the server Client, to find the (example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts):

```
 rclcpp::Client<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts::SharedPtr init = node->create_client<example_interfaces::srv::AddTwoInts>("init");
```

In my custom package I made some .srv files that I want to use, do I need a Header file as well ?

```
sum.srv
#include "my_package/srv/sum.hpp"
```

Obviously I don't have this .hpp file so it will throw an error.
Do I need to make one myself or can I generate this file ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344042/%5Bros2%5D-service-header-files/) by [jlepers](https://answers.ros.org/users/46408/jlepers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2020-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The headers are generated and not written by hand. You can generate them using the `rosidl_generate_interfaces` CMake macro ([examnple here](https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces/blob/0f2618147034527a46f8a852822d62a8cea8e758/CMakeLists.txt#L16-L18))

There doesn't seem to be an up-to-date tutorial explaining how to define and use custom interfaces at the moment.

I recommend you to create a package with only your custom messages / services files (you can look at https://github.com/ros2/example_interfaces for an example)

And use them in your package (using https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/35674eb17494ab3f67cc5fbe5f127c614be2220b/rclcpp/minimal_client as an example)

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlepers](https://answers.ros.org/users/46408/jlepers/) on 2020-02-14**:
Thank you, I was trying something similar.
Is it possible that I need to install ROS2 by source to use rosidl_default_generators instead of ROS2 Debian packages?

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-14**:\

> Is it possible that I need to install ROS2 by source to use rosidl_default_generators instead of ROS2 Debian packages?

You should be able to use it from debian packages. You'll need to make sure that that package is installed (though I believe it is installed by default).

```
apt-get list --installed | grep rosidl-default-generators
```

**Comment by [jlepers](https://answers.ros.org/users/46408/jlepers/) on 2020-02-14**:
edit:

```
apt list --installed | grep rosidl-default-generators
```

output:

```
ros-dashing-rosidl-default-generators/now 0.7.0-1bionic.20191016.185016 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 0.7.0-1bionic.20191210.230356]
```

I guess this is fine, but I still have cmake troubles with the find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED) command.

**Comment by [jlepers](https://answers.ros.org/users/46408/jlepers/) on 2020-02-14**:
Should I open a new question ?

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-14**:
Yes please. Can you make sure to add your full package.xml and CMakeLists (with the comment lines, starting with # removed for readability) ? This will help diagnose the issue